# Stick Div to Bottom of screen till content gets longer

Tags: html, css

Stick div to bottom of screen and when the content gets longer than the screen and you have to scroll make the div go down with the content but wont come shorter than bottom of the screen.

QUESTION: How do i get a div to stick to bottom of screen and move down when the content gets longer than the screen where you have to scroll?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do i get a div to stick to bottom of screen and move down when the content gets longer than the screen where you have to scrol

Comment: Either make sure the content before the div covers nearly the whole screen or use a onScroll listener to change the div's properties

Answer (score 0):

You have to position your HTML content the right way. Let's assume you want the footer tag at the bottom, so you need to put it as the last element in your body tag. 
If you want to "simulate" space on your page before the actual content is put in, you can add a div with a specific height (for example 800px) that will stretch your page.